# Name of the behavior of numpy calling class methods if defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've noticed that if I have methods with the same name of numpy methods in a class, numpy tends to use the methods defined in the class rather than its own. For example:

```
import numpy as np  # using numpy 1.13.1


class PizzaPie:
    def __init__(self, slice_angles: list, topping: str='Cheese'):
        try:
            if sum(slice_angles) > 360:
                raise Exception('A pizza cannot have more than 360 degrees cut '
                             'from it.')
            if sum(slice_angles) == 360:
                self._angles = slice_angles
            else:
                self._angles = slice_angles + [360 - sum(slice_angles)]
        except TypeError:
            # maybe slices are described as complex numbers...?
            total_pie = 0
            for pizza_slice in slice_angles:
                angle = (
                    np.arctan(pizza_slice.imag / pizza_slice.real)
                    * (180 / np.pi)
                )
                total_pie += angle
            if total_pie == 360:
                self._angles = slice_angles
            else:
                # make the left over slice a simple number in degrees.
                self._angles = slice_angles + [360 - total_pie]

        self._topping = topping

    @property
    def topping(self):
        return self._topping

    @topping.setter
    def topping(self, new):
        """Only able to add additional toppings. Removing is too messy."""
        self._topping = self._topping + ', ' + str(new)

    @property
    def slices(self):
        """Returns the number of slices"""
        return len(self.angles)

    def cos(self):
        """Returns the slice number and the cosine of the slice angle as a tuple"""
        return [(sl, np.cos(a*(np.pi/180)))
                for sl, a in enumerate(self._angles)
                ]

    def imag(self):
        """Returns the imaginary portion of the slice angles. Weird huh?"""
        return [(sl, np.imag(a)) for sl, a in enumerate(self._angles)]


mypie = PizzaPie([90, 45, 30, 30, 35])
my_imag_pie = PizzaPie([(20+5j), 90.0, (3+4j)], topping='Dark Matter')

print(np.cos(mypie))
print(np.imag(my_imag_pie))
```

(of course this code is completely fabricated and fictional, but it serves as a simple example of something I'm trying to do. And it's fun to think about Imaginary Pizzas...)

But you'll notice that running the above code will return the bound method `PizzaPie.imag` instead of *calling* `PizzaPie.imag()` (in Python 3.5.3) while `PizzaPie.cos` is called when `np.cos(mypie)` is written. Is this a bug in numpy 1.13? Also, what is this behavior called where numpy will prefer to use class defined methods with the same name?

Sidenote: I know that I can call `np.cos(mypie)` and then `np.imag(my_imag_pie))()`, but this is ugly and inconsistent. I'm also worried that if someone uses my PizzaPie class with a later version of numpy, it will break and I don't want to support different code for different versions of numpy if at all possible.

Comment: ["delegation"](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/ufunc-delegation-to-object-method-td30270.html) is what I've heard people use but don't know whether that's an official technical term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PizzaPie` class contains an array, but is not an `ndarray` subclass. Typically a `np` function tries to turn its input into an array, and then apply the function to that, possibly invoking the corresponding method.

`np.cos` is compiled, but we can get an idea of what it attempts to do by giving it a list, specifically a list that can't be made into a simple numeric array:

```
In [51]: np.cos([np.arange(3),3,[1,2]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-0d338a087870> in <module>()
----> 1 np.cos([np.arange(3),3,[1,2]])

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cos'
In [52]: np.array([np.arange(3),3,[1,2]])
Out[52]: array([array([0, 1, 2]), 3, list([1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

`np.cos` has turned the input into an object array and tried to do `[x.cos() for x in np.array(input)]`.  For your case it does work, since you defined a `cos` method.

`np.imag` is Python code, and attempts to return the `imag` attribute (property).  It assumes `imag` is a property, not a method, which is why you get the unevaluated method.

```
np.imag(val)
    return val.imag
    # or
    return np.asanyarray(val).imag

In [53]: np.imag([np.arange(3),3,[1,2]])
Out[53]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
```

Try setting `imag` as a property.  Then it should evaluate.

Comment: Ah-ha! That worked and thank you for the educational answer.